# Quantum mechanics: Potential and harmonic

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider a particle in the potential:

$V = mw^{2}x^{2}/2$ for $x>0$

$V = \infty$ for $x<0$

I thought in a way to solve this problem, but i am not sure if we can do it:
Can't we just insert the delta Kronecker here?

That is:
$\psi = \psi_{HS}*\delta^{x'}_{|x'|}$

Where HS means Harmonic simple

So that for x'>0 it behaves like any other harmonic oscillator, but for x'<0 (|x'| different x'), it is zero

Comment: Almost. What about functions that are not zero at $x=0$?

Comment: I think the potential is very different. It's no longer a Harmonic oscillator potential. Why then would the wavefunction remain the same? Do you have any arguments in favor of that?

Comment: I agree, just think that the potential is no more symmetric respect to the y-axis: unlike in the harmonic oscillator, the solutions here are not eigenstates of the parity operator

Comment: @Tachyon209 the potential is not different but the boundary condition is.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero well, you could say so IF you are only talking about the right half of the potential. I get it. That's the way it is solved. I just wanted to provoke OP's thought on this thing.

Answer (score 0):

The boundary condition here forces a $0$ at the origin.  You should then be able to restrict your initial solutions to those with a node at $x=0$.